# Ubuntu Touch Desktop/Dock Mode

Tags: dock, mode

I recently installed Ubuntu Touch dualboot on my Nexus 4.

I am considering buying a Slimport HDMI adapter and want to know if Desktop (Dock) mode is functional in the latest release of Ubuntu Touch (Trusty) for my device? I'd love to be able to have a full Desktop to carry around with me in my pocket!

Please let me know if/when this feature is/will be available?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the information, that full convergence is expected for 14.10 or 15.04 (ubuntu version that is)
I'd suppose full convergence will also include Desktop/Docking feature.

Comment: Please add a source, where did you find the information?

Comment: It looks like maybe delayed further...